# System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session not working on Azure server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

We have one LoginContinueController. In the Index() method we are have written the following code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var Sessionid = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;

    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Session["AuthToken"] = guid;

    // now create a new cookie with this guid value  
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("AuthToken", guid));
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Sensor", new { });
}
```

Then we are redirecting to AppController Index() method:
In the Index() method of SensorController "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthToken"]" is becoming null giving Null Reference Exception.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthToken"].ToString().Equals(Request.Cookies["AuthToken"].Value))
    {
        return ShowApphData();
    }
}
```

The code is working perfectly fine when we run via Visual Studio 2015 without any issues, but after hosting on a IIS it is not working. Can someone help please?

Comment: Are you using multiple instances of your app in azure ?

Comment: Hi @AnirudhaGupta. No we have only instance of the app on Azure. What's strange is in the same VM where we develop our code - the app is running with VS 2015. And in the same VM when publish and host the website it is not working.